# AWS Signed URLs from SQL

Tags: python, sql, django, amazon-s3, boto3

I've got a lot of static content in an S3 bucket that doesn't have public read access.  I want to provide access to this content by generating signed urls.

I'm using python and boto3 library for most use cases.  I have a few raw SQL queries though that pull the URLs straight from the database and dump them right to the browser.  I'd rather not have to loop through all the results on the server, convert the urls to signed urls using python, and then send it to the browser.  I'd prefer that there be a SQL equivalent of this magic.

Instead of

`select imageFileUrl from photos;`

I'd like to be able to do something like

`select signed_url(imageFileUrl) from photos;`

The python boto class / function for this seems to be `botocore.signers.RequestSigner.sign()`

Upon looking deeper the real meat of it (for my use case at least) appears to be `botocore.auth.HmacV1QueryAuth` and its `get_signature`, `canonical_string`, `sign_string` and `_inject_signature` functions.

Has anyone solved this problem before?  Am I on the right track?

I'm using python 3, django 2, and postgresql 10.

Edit:
I may consider making my own cursor using the cursor_factory param discussed here. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#connection-and-cursor-subclasses

Perhaps find a way to pass in a function map so any column that needs special attention can get it right at the point of origin vs looping the result set again. We’ll see.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some Python that can generate a pre-signed URL with Python 2.7 (which is the version used by Redshift):

```py
import base64
import hmac
import sha
import urllib
import time

SECRET_KEY = 'abc123'
OBJECT = '/my-bucket/foo'
DURATION = 120

# Expiry time
expiry_epoch = int(time.time() + DURATION)

# Generate signature
h = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY, "GET\n\n\n" + str(expiry_epoch) + "\n" + OBJECT, sha)
signature = urllib.quote_plus(base64.encodestring(h.digest()).strip())

# Put this after the URL
print("?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAxxx&Expires=" + str(expiry_epoch) + "&Signature=" + signature)
```

It will output the parameters to append to the URL to permit access via the pre-signed URL.

You will need to put your Secret Key into the code.

Hopefully you can then turn this code into a User-Defined Function in Redshift.

Comment: Thanks. We are using an on premise postgresql server but postgresql also allows user defined functions in python. So this would certainly be one option.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I incorrectly assumed Redshift, but I see you are using PostgreSQL. The same general method would still apply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, I can't think of any other ways to avoid looping through and generate the signatures. Also s3 doesn't support generating signatures for multiple files in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just looping over the results.  I still think it can be done with a custom cursor instead.  I may do that eventually.

Here's a gist that shows the kind of raw sql helper I created. https://gist.github.com/cspinelive/9ba8c4034b42c00683ef175f54068546  It allows clean code like this:

```
from Acme.db import AcmeQuery

sql = 'select id, "pdf_url" from books where status=%(status)s limit 10'
params = {'status': 'A'}

s3signer = AcmeQuery.S3Signer(cols=['pdf_url'])

rows = AcmeQuery(sql, params=params, row_modifier=s3signer).run()
```

the here's the meat of it (see the gist for the full code)

```
class AcmeQuery(object):
  def run(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
          cursor.execute(sql, params)

          # covert list of tuples to list of dictionaries
          rows = dictfetchall(cursor)

          # post process each row with a custom function
          # function must accept the as a dictionary as its first argument
          # other arguments may be accepted as well via kwargs
          if self.row_modifier:
              for row in rows:
                  self.row_modifier.func(row, **self.row_modifier.params)

   return rows

class RowModifier(object):
    def __init__(self, func, params=None):
        self.func = func
        self.params = params or {}
```